# web2py request.args(0) permissions

Tags: python, database, permissions, web2py

I'm working on a project, 
this project must have many users, each user can create for examples many support tickets and he could see them and edit them, but he is not allowed to access any other ticket, which not belong to him
so for example :

```
def edit_ticket():
    record = db.e_ticket(request.args(0),active=True) or redirect(URL('error'))
    form=crud.update(db.e_ticket,record,next='view_ticket/[id]')
    return dict(form=form)
```

in this way with (`request.args(0)`) the user can edit every ticket in the system just to change the id to any other id and it will work
edit_ticket/[id]

so i changed the `request.args(0)` with `auth.user_id`, it was a great solution as i thought! but when we've many users so only the 1st and 2ed user could edit this thier tickets the next users cannot do that and receive an error when they do this "edit_Ticket/[id]"

```
Error the document doesn't exist
```

what should i do to prevent users from bypassing their privilege

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it shouldn't be:

`db.e_ticket(request.args(0),user_id==auth.user_id,active==True)`

but

`db.e_ticket(request.args(0),user_id=auth.user_id,active=True)` -

because here we're passing function arguments and not query conditions

Answer (score 0):

web2py has buildin user access control. please reference the [web2py book](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/08):

users should login to edit their ticket, so you can use @auth.requires_login() to decorate edit_ticket(). In edit_ticket() you can check whether the user_id has the ticket_id first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into using [authorization and CRUD](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/08#Authorization-and-CRUD) (and generally [how to set permissions](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/08#Authorization) on particular database records).

Note, you can't replace `request.args(0)` with `auth.user_id`. `request.args(0)` is referring to the id of the e_ticket record, not the user id. If the e_ticket table includes a field referencing the user id (e.g., e_ticket.user_id), then you could add `user_id=auth.user_id` as a condition.

```
next='view_ticket/[id]'
```

You should use the `URL()` function to create URLs -- `URL(f='view_ticket',args=[id])`. Also, what is `[id]` supposed to be -- I don't see any reference to `id` in the code?

Comment: it shouldn't:
`db.e_ticket(request.args(0),user_id==auth.user_id,active==True)`
but
`db.e_ticket(request.args(0),user_id=auth.user_id,active=True)`
- because here they're function arguments and not query conditions!, thank you

Comment: Oops, you are right (and the web2py online book is wrong -- that will be corrected). I have edited the above accordingly.